# Factor Analysis in R, Error

Tags: r, dataframe, factor-analysis

I have typed the following command in R

```
factanal(TD, factor = 10, rotation = "varimax", scores = "regression")
```

where TD is my data frame containing 41 variables

I am getting the following error

> Error in factanal(TD, factor = 10, rotation = "varimax", scores = "regression") : 
>     unable to optimize from this starting value

Can someone help me with this error.

Comment: the error message sais it all: try using a different starting value.

Comment: Can you add `control = list(trace = T)` argument to `factanal` call and show us the output?

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem, I found that adding the control argument "lower", which specifies the lower bound for uniqueness (default = 0.005), helps!

For my problem a value of 0.00000001 gave results. Afterwards, it turned out that I had some variables with very low values of uniqueness. So it might be that you have created 4 dummies from a factor with 4 levels, thereby creating redundancy.

So my tips:
1. Play with the lower argument
2. once it works, check which variables have a very low uniqueness, take them out of the dataframe & run the factor analysis again

Answer (score 0):

There is a "start" option in factanal like this:

```
factanal(TD,factor=10,rotation="varimax",scores="regression",start=rep(0,41))
```

But without your data/detailed output can't tell what exactly the problem is.